# Field based joining of two files in UNIX

Tags: linux, shell, unix, join, merge

I have a requirement wherein `fileA` contains a list of rows with several columns, one of the column is `emaillist` which are named as `emaillist[1,2,3,..]`. I have defined another file `fileB` where I have assigned values to `emailist[1,2,3,..]` variable. I read `fileA` and want to read the `emailist` which is defined in `fileB`.

**FileA:**

```
XXX1 YYY1 emailist1
XXX2 YYY2 emailist2
```

**FileB:**

```
emailist1=abcd@xyz.com 
emailist2=xyz@zbc.com
```

**Shell script:**

```
Read fileA

email = $3
```

Here is my challenge, how to read `emailist1` defined in `fileB`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `join` command:

```
$ cat fileA
XXX1 YYY1 emailist1
XXX2 YYY2 emailist2

$ cat fileB
emailist1 abcd@xyz.com 
emailist2 xyz@zbc.com

$ join -1 3 -2 1 -o '1.1 1.2 2.2' <(sort fileA -k3,3) <(sort fileB)
XXX1 YYY1 abcd@xyz.com 
XXX2 YYY2 xyz@zbc.com
```

The `join` command required the data to be sorted first so we `sort` file by `emaillist` then join on `column 3` in `file 1` with `column 1` in `file 2` i.e `-1 3 -2 1`. The `-o` option is used to specify which field to output in much the same way, as you didn't clearly specify I guess field one and two from `fileA` and field 2 from `fileB`: `1.1 1.2 2.2`.

*Note: change the `=` to a space in `fileB` like `sed 's/=/ /' fileB`.*

Comment: As long as you have `bash` 4.x (`bash` 3.2 does not support [_process substitution_](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)), you can deal with the `=` to blank mapping by using `sed` on the data file either before or after it is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read `fileB` first and add the values to an associative array, then when `fileA` is read, substitute the third column with the value in the array. This logic can be easily implemented with `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { sub(/=/," "); a[$1]=$2; next } $3 in a { $3=a[$3] }1' fileB fileA
```

Results:

```
XXX1 YYY1 abcd@xyz.com
XXX2 YYY2 xyz@zbc.com
```